# Image watermarking in wavelet domain (data hiding in images)

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, image-segmentation, steganography

I am working and researching on Image watermarking/steganography and I'm stuck at a point and want to know which technique is better in image processing for data hiding.

Bit Plane Complexity Segmentation OR CDMA Spread spectrum.

Can some experts give their opinion on both techniques and which one is better and why? like advantages and disadvantages or comparison of both

Thanks a lot.

So, I just want to hide some text in a color or grayscale image using wavelet trasform.

I could use either bpcs or cdma spread spectrum technique. I want to know which one should go for and why.

This is for learning purpose and no particular application.

Thanks. Please let me know if u need any specific info.

Comment: What are your own findings so far?

Comment: Here is the bit I know until now.   BPCS is very useful for high capacity steganography whereas cdma spread spectrum does not provide high capacity. However, cdma SS technique is more robust and secure in sense that multiple users can use the same channel for transmission and its secure and difficult to decrypt the image i.e to find the hidden data in image.

Comment: I cant find comparisons online for these both and quite confused and hence asked this question here, to get more insight on the techniques. any comments/feedback would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For image watermarking, I suggest you not to use wavelet Transform.
Instead, you can use an efficient technique in terms of robustness and transparency, based on the Quantization Index Modulation (QIM). You can also use a variant of it which is called "Spread Transform Dither Modulation".
Good luck